# Select all possible column values where column value equals a value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this :

```
+----+----------+------------+
| id |  server  |    name    |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 |  server1 | PlayerOne  |
|  2 |  server2 | PlayerOne  |
|  3 |  server1 | PlayerTwo  |
|  4 |  server1 | PlayerFour |
+----+----------+------------+
```

My goal is to select data to have something like this :

```
+-----------+------------------+
|   name    |     serverList   |
+-----------+------------------+
| PlayerOne | server1, server2 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

I tried to `SELECT server,name AS result` but with no results..

Thanks to anyone that ca help me.

Comment: Why does only player one appear in the output?

Comment: This is a mistake. All players should appear with their respective servers. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using `mysql v8.0` you can use `group_concat()` function

```
select name, group_concat(server, ',') as serverlist from tableA
group by name
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` existed in MySQL long before v8

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I added a ``DISTINCT`` into the ``GROUP_CONCAT`` to server, in order to remove duplicates.
+1